How to determine 'table type' for Iceberg tables in Athena
I have some Athena databases which contain a number of tables, and I know some of these tables use the Iceberg format. It's important to me to know which are Iceberg tables, because those will allow a greater range of INSERT, UPDATE, and ALTER queries that the basic EXTERNAL table type.
When we create Iceberg tables in Athena we set the table_type property like this:
CREATE TABLE my_table
-- specify columns, partition, location, etc
TBLPROPERTIES ('table_type' ='ICEBERG')

How can I check the value of this property from Athena when working with tables? If that's not possible, what's a suitable proxy for this so that I can determine whether a table is an Iceberg table (vs an External table)?

In Athena DESCRIBE FORMATTED [TABLE] (docs) returns 'table_type' = 'ICEBERG' when querying Iceberg tables.
SHOW CREATE TABLE works when the table is created via Athena. Initially I thought it worked only when the table is created with format-version = 2, which is the default when creating the table via Athena -- when creating it via spark.sql(), instead, the default format-version is 1. However, even when creating
it via spark.sql() and specifying format-version = 2 in the DDL, SHOW CREATE TABLE doesn't work.
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES doesn't seem to work as of today.

I find that SHOW CREATE TABLE works, but SHOW TBLPROPERTIES does not work.

Thanks for the info, I corrected my answer.

Can you python with boto3 library and pull table info.  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/get_table.html
Have used this option as there's metadata you can only get through the console or through api such as when a column is created etc.
Just another option to get additional info without going to the console

Thanks Jeff. What specifically within this response could I check to determine Iceberg vs non-Iceberg?

I'm waiting for our implementation of glacier to confirm but expect it to be  'TableType': 'string',
